# No Module found named 'XlsxWriter' python3 VScode

Tags: python, excel

having an issue with importing modules and them not being recognized in VSCode

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import XlsxWriter

#Import excel file
dataframe = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ntanner\Downloads\trial-excel.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Chemical Audit Log')

dataframe2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ntanner\Downloads\trial-excel.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Defect Chemical Log')

#display the data frame
dataframe
```

When I run this from command prompt, as I am on windows, I use the following command:
`C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\Coding\xlsx practice>python test.py`
here is the result:

```
PS C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\Coding\xlsx practice> python .\test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ntanner\Documents\Coding\xlsx practice\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import xlsxwriter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'
```

In VS Code, I have tried running the program on every interpreter using the built in terminal. I am not entirely sure what the differences of them are, regardless, I get the same result as when I run it from command prompt.
I have installed and uninstalled the xlsxwriter using `pip install xlsx` multiple times and I get the result:

```
Requirement already satisfied: xlsxwriter in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (3.0.3)
```

I have verified that xlsxwriter is inside of C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages.

Any ideas? If you need more info I can provide it.

Answer (score 0):

A No module error usually means the library is installed. You can try a

```
pip install XlsxWriter
```

Comment: Did you mean uninstalled? I have done `pip install xlsxwriter` as mentioned in post.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shown in the the traceback about an unexpected keyword argument is not the same as the error in the title about not having xlsxwriter installed.

The traceback error message is saying that pandas [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) doesn't have a parameter called `index`, which you have added in your code.

Comment: I updated it, I don't know why I was getting those index errors but I removed index and now its just the import xlsxwriter error

Comment: The following shows several methods to install and check the installation of XlsxWriter, including in VS Code: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-xlsxwriter